# Form for each items in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I create dynamic form by each objects? I search solution good for SEO.

I have HTML like this:

```
<% @products[0..2].each do |p| %>
    <div class="catalog-item">
        <img class="catalog-item__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        <h2 class="catalog-item__title"><%= p.name %></h2>
        <select name="" class="input input-container__input">
          <%= p.product_prices.each do |pp| %>                
              <option value=""><%= pp.weight %> kg - <%= pp.price %> USD</option>
          <% end %>
        </select>

        <input type="date" name="" class="input input-container__input">

        <%= link_to "Details", details_path(p.id), class: "btn", remote: true %>
        <%= link_to 'Add', add_to_cart_path(p.id), class: 'btn btn--icon', remote: true %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I have try like this:

```
<% @products[0..2].each do |p| %>
  <% form_for $product do |f| %>
    <div class="catalog-item">
        <img class="catalog-item__img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
        <h2 class="catalog-item__title"><%= p.name %></h2>
        <select name="whatsname?" class="input input-container__input">
          <%= p.product_prices.each do |pp| %>                
              <option value=""><%= pp.weight %> kg - <%= pp.price %> USD</option>
          <% end %>
        </select>

        <input type="date" name="" class="input input-container__input">

        <%= link_to "Details", details_path(p.id), class: "btn", remote: true %>
        <%= link_to 'Add', add_to_cart_path(p.id), class: 'btn btn--icon', remote: true %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I don't know how can I get access to data from multiple forms. And I don't know what should be in the product object when objects are generated.

Comment: That code should produce a select field with an option for each product_price for each product (although it's not clear what the `[0..2]` range is doing). What's your problem with it? (Although you'd be much better off using the Rails helpers than building your own form objects, in most cases.)

Comment: Forget about products [0..2]. What you can see here is ok, but I want to implement forms support for it. And then the problem arises. I do not know how to do this. If I add a form in a loop, it will not be displayed or will not work. This is because the fields are duplicated everywhere when adding X of the same forms.

Comment: So, share the code you actually want help with then! Don't share irrelevant code - it just confuses things. What code to use to "add a form in a loop"? And what happens when you do? And what do you want to happen that's different?

Comment: I added example.

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with your code. Your current use of `form_for` is broken because you're passing in the wrong object: you should be using `p`, because that's the object in your current iteration. (You don't appear to have defined `$product` so things aren't going to work at all if you pass that object to `form_for` because it's `nil`.)

Also, please, stop trying to build the form manually and use the Rails helpers. [Read the fine manual](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html). Rails forms work well and make everything straightforward but, as with everything Rails, you need to work with the framework if you want things to work. If you work outside the framework, you really need to know what you're doing because otherwise you'll be fighting Rails all the way - and why would you use Rails if you were going to do that?

If you're not sure what you're dealing with (`@products`, `p`, whatever), try using the `byebug` gem and add breakpoints and inspect the state of your variables.

===Edit following the comments

It looks, following much exploration in the comments(!) that you want code something like this:

```rb
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= form_with scope: product.name, url: PATH_TO_FORM_ENDPOINT do |form| %>
    <%= form.label :prices, "Prices for #{product.name}" %>
    <%= form.select :prices, product.product_prices.to_a %>
    <%= form.hidden_field :id, value: product.id %>
    <%= form.submit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This should produce a series of individual forms, one for each product that lists the prices available. Obviously, because you've not shared the data structure or routes in your app, you will need to update the code accordingly, but hopefully this gives you some idea.

(Adding the scope to the form makes sure that each will be named differently, so you can distinguish between them when the user submits a form. The url will presumably be the same in each case. And, hopefully, you can see how the Rails forms helpers make it much simpler to compose your form!)

Comment: I know how can I create forms. Problem is in this specific case. I have multiple products and for it product prices and an input date for each elements. I would like to get in controller: product price id and date.

Comment: It's really not clear what you actually need help with. If the problem's in your controller then you need to share the controller code. It sounds like you need a variable that contains a collection of your products - something like `@products = Product.all`! If you want specific help, though, you need to do enough work yourself to be able to ask specific questions. Otherwise you're asking us to guess without much information!

Comment: I have list of products and products are displayed correct. I don't know how can I transform this dynamic data from multiple products to one form, when example in thread create multiple forms and propably it never will work.

Comment: You need to define what you want the form to look like. For example, do you want the user to be able to see a list of products, to pick one, and then be shown all the price options for that product? Or do you want them to see all products and the price options for each at the same time? The first of these requires interaction - either specific Rails actions to generate individual forms once the product has been chosen, or JS on the front end if you want a dynamic page.

Comment: I would like all products to be available, and the pricing options by select. The user should be able to select one product with one price option. Then this product go to shopping cart.

Comment: I can use "form_with" and manually get this data from forms. But probably this is not rails-style solution.

Comment: Perhaps share the best code you have, then, so we can help straight away? But as I said right at the start, you're not making use of the [Rails form helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease). Rails works best if you use its ways of doing things. `form_with` is the correct way to do things (if you're in Rails 6) so perhaps read up on that. First, you have to decide what you're POSTing, then configure `form_with` appropriately. In this case, you seem to be POSTing custom data, so probably use `url: YOUR_PATH`.

Comment: I've added an edit to the answer with a best guess at the sort of code you'll need, but you have to think about what you're trying to achieve and make sure that you send the right data.